# Почему не работает валидатор для redux-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

При помощи `redux-form` делаю форму. Соответственно, примерно так выглядит форма:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field name={name} component={component} validate={validators}/>
</form>
```

Ещё в отдельном файле у меня есть валидаторы:

```
export const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Это полe обязательное';
export const nonMatchPipe = answer => answer.match('\\|') ? 'Ответ не должен содержать символ |' : undefined;
```

А теперь возникает интересный феномен. Вот такой набор валидаторов работает нормально:

```
<Field name={name} component={component} validate={[required, nonMatchPipe]}/>
```

И если оставить валидатор `required`, то всё тоже нормально:

```
<Field name={name} component={component} validate={[required]}/>
```

Но если я оставляю только валидатор `nonMatchPipe`, то возникает ошибка

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`.
```

Почему возникает ошибка? Как её решить?

Comment: Похоже что аргумент `answer` в функции `nonMatchPipe` не успевает с инициализацией что и говорит `undefined`. Можно конечно еще так попробовать - `export const nonMatchPipe = answer => { if(answer) { return answer.match('\\|') ? 'Ответ не должен содержать символ |' : undefined;` }

Comment: @dresser сейчас попробую. А что это вообще происходит с точки зрения JS? Почему он может не успевать с инициализацией? Очень неочевидная ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не очень хорошо понимают механизмы `JS`, но да, почему-то без предварительной проверки на то, что текст существует, вызов `match()` у текста выбрасывает ошибку. Решается это довольно простым способом:

```
export const nonMatchPipe = answer => answer && answer.match('\\|')
    ? 'Ответ не должен содержать символ |'
    : undefined;
```

Это немного похоже на проверку `Objects.requireNonNull()` в Java, только в Java это необязательная к исполнению рекомендация, а в JS из-за этого возникает ошибка.

#### UPD от 22.07.21

Больше похожая на правду причина ошибки заключалась в том, что валидатор вызывается при любом изменении формы, в том числе при изменении полей, которые находятся в той же форме, что и поле, в котором установлено валидатор. И если поле, в котором находится валидатор, у нас не имеет значения, то попытка провалидировать `undefined` вызывает ошибку.

Например, в нашей форме есть поля `name` и `surname`. На `surname` установлен такой валидатор:

```
export const nonMatchPipe = surname => surname.match(/\|/g) 
    ? 'В фамилии не может быть символа |' 
    : undefined;
```

Если мы работаем с полем `name`, то это создаёт вызов валидаторов. И если валидатор вызовется у пустого поля `surname`, то это создаст ошибку из-за попытки вызвать функцию `match()` у `undefined`.